# What are the pros and cons of hosting multiple domains on one VPS?

Tags: web-hosting

I have one main company website (lots of traffic), and 10+ personal sites that I host for friends (small traffic).

I'm wondering if there are risks if I just host them all on one VPS instead of having a separate VPS for the company website.

Eg. If one of those sites installs a malicious plugin, could it affect my main site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a sense, a VPS host already hosts thousands of separate company web sites already so you doing the same thing is no different. The only disadvantage is, if the VPS goes down, they all go down.

If you are paying for traffic, of course, then that cost will go up but you say that is minimal.

Should one of the sites get heavily loaded, it can slow down all your sites depending on how your host has your server configured.

One concern is malicious code between sites. This can be locked down with proper security measures such as Jails in FreeBSD or containers in Linux, not to mention setting all the usual permissions and user levels afforded by *nix/BSD systems to isolate each site as much as possible.

An advantage is it saves you money by not buying more server installations and keeping everything under one roof.

Comment: Great advice :) +1

Comment: @Rob - What about malicious code on one site affecting other sites on the same host? That's my major concern because those 10 sites include non-tech friend's Wordpress sites, and who knows what plugins they're installing.

Comment: @jetlej I should add that to my list but proper security measures to isolate each site should take care of that. With FreeBSD, you would put each site in its own jail so they can't break out. In Linux, their thing is called "containers", I believe.